# How to build mathomatic lib for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

I want to compile the mathomatic(CAS) library for iPhone. I am not able to find any place where to define the **"HANDHELD"** flag which helps to compile the library for mobile devices.

You can find the library from [mathomatic](http://www.mathomatic.org).

I have already compiled library but when I am trying to use that library then xcode is throwing error like "libmathomatic.a doesn't contain slice for i386" so, I have tried to get the architecture info using `lipo` command so, it showing `x86_64`. It might be looks like compiled library is for OSX not for iPhone so, what changes I need to do to compile it for iPhone? I have already taken look into `make` file but I am not getting how to define or change the architecture.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compiling libraries for iOS is not trivial; once you've got the code compiled you then need to create fat binaries for armv7, i386, etc.  You are better off searching github or something for someone who has already done this work.

Comment: Yes. I already did but didn't found anything that's why I am here :)

Comment: You'd add that flag to the compiler flags, as `-DHANDHELD`. But it does not help *compiling*. The aim of `HANDHELD` is reducing memory usage at *runtime*. So it your app builds but crashes after starting it, then setting that flag would help. If it doesn't build an executable version in the first place, then setting that flag won't help.